# Throw exception instead of returning default value

Tags: exception, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and want to use it in unit tests.

What I don't like is mocks created with `Mockito.mock(Class<T>)` return default values (like `null`) for methods that have no behavior explicitly defined. Instead, I want them to throw an exception in this case so I know that I need to add this definition.

I tried the following:

```
SomeType m = mock( SomeType.class, new ThrowsException( new SomeRuntimeException( ... ) ) );
when( m.a() ).thenReturn( ... );

m.a();  // ok
m.b();  // throws exception
```

But that doesn't work because the exception is thrown already during the call to `when()`.

Is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: +1: Interesting use case! I'd never thought of this one :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace

`when( m.a() ).thenReturn( ... );`

with

`doReturn( ... ).when(m).a();`

Comment: +1 Thanks! The javadoc of doReturn explains the difference between the two lines. It also exactly refers my case. :-)

Comment: I wonder what Mockito's reason is for not providing a way to throw an exception for unstubbed methods.  Using a default Answer of ThrowsException + doReturn does work, but it effectively means that you can never use 'when', which is the preferred method.

Comment: Do you mean something like the following:
Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(m).a();

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you explained it a little.